# How did 毋 + 乃 compound to mean "it's none other than"?

Tags: etymology

When I first happened upon [毋乃](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%AF%8B%E4%B9%83#Chinese), I first guessed its meaning as "not this". Then I consulted p 1007,  [*ABC Chinese–English Comprehensive Dictionary* (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABC_Chinese%E2%80%93English_Dictionary). I can't access the ["slightly revised through July 2005" ed.](https://wenlin.com/abc%22)

> <sup>2</sup>wúnǎi 毋乃 F.E. <wr.> Is it not ... ?

1. So why was my first guess wrong? Why doesn't 毋乃 mean "not this"?
2. How does 毋乃 compound to mean "Is it not ... ?"

[image]

Comment: You are almost correct. 毋乃is used in a negative interrogative sentence. So, instead of "not this", it is "Is it not this?".

Comment: @joehua Thanks. Don't hesitate to expound your comment in an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a proper and authoritative dictionary, **please**.

in 國語辭典, maintained by ministry of education, taiwan ; “毋乃” is explained as:

> 豈非、莫非、未免、只恐，表示推測的語氣。

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=Z00000158798

and, the quoted source translated “毋乃” as “it is none other than” is, incorrect.

> Why doesn't 毋乃 mean "not this"?

misleaded by entry level dictionary. think about “hot dog”, or “greenhouse”:

separately, “green” is a colour, and “house” is a building. so, if one naively guess that “greenhouse” is a building in green colour, it’s . . .

have fun :)

Comment: Sorry! I can't read (much) Chinese, so that's why I've been using Wiktionary. I'll seek better sources.

Comment: @水巷孑蠻:Apropros "greenhouse", in the doghouse does not always mean one is in a kennel!

Comment: Thanks. I edited my question. Does it change your answer? I'm uncertain if you answered question 1.

Comment: I use 國語辭典 often but would not call it "authoritative." It contains a lot of mistakes. Be aware of this fact when consulting the dictionary. I might still keep the email in which I asked them to change "天涯笑此時" to "天涯哭此時".

Comment: @joehua Your comment should be "stickied" or blazoned permanently somewhere on this website. Have you asked the moderators to?

Comment: @AYX.CLDR Thanks for the suggestion. I don't use stackexchange often. I don't know how to do that. I didn't know such a feature is available.